# Why am I getting a Type Mismatch Error when filtering SumProduct in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pretty simple Macro but for the life of me, can't figure out why I keep on getting type mismatch.  I have tried other versions of the formula and same issue.

In one worksheet,I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Rng2 = Target
Call Sub1

End Sub
```

In the workbook, I have a module that has:

```
Option Explicit

Public Rng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range

Sub Sub1()

Set Rng1 = Rng2.Offset(0, -2)

'Debug.Print Evaluate("=SumProduct(--(Rng1 > 0), Rng1, Rng2)")
'Debug.Print [SUM(if(Rng1 > 0, Rng1 * Rng2))]
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Rng1 > 0), Rng1, Rng2)

End Sub
```

None of those work.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass your `Target` as a parameter. Also, there is no reason to create another variable for your range. `Rng2 = Target` so just use `Target`. Since you are not passing your variable, your range carries a value of `Nothing`. Trying to take the sumproduct of `Nothing` is problematic

Comment: When I isolate the code and just do: Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct( Rng1, Rng2), it works.  It's the filtering part that messes things up I believe.

Comment: `Public Sub Sub1(ByVal rng As Range)`, then do `Sub1 Target` (no need for `Call`) ..and `Sub1` could use a better name - note that `SUB1` is a valid cell address, so that may cause problems further down the line.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a different sub and rng name in my spreadsheet.  I tried both of your suggestions and I still get type mismatch.  If I remove "--(Rng1 > 0)" I don't get an error, but obviously I get the wrong number as well.

Comment: I want to sumproduct only the rows in Rng1 the are greater than 0.  That last sumproduct equation I provided works in regular excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Which line is throwing the type mismatch error, specifically? The prior feedback was to address the unnecessary global variables

Comment: Originally, I had: ```Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Rng1 > 0), Rng1, Rng2)```, which is giving me a type mismatch.  I got suggestions to try: ```Evaluate("=SumProduct(--(Rng1 > 0), Rng1, Rng2)")``` and ```[SUM(if(Rng1 > 0, Rng1 * Rng2))]``` which presumably should give me the same answer.  They all give me type mismatch.  I've narrowed it down to the "filtering" aspect that causes the error, but not sure what I need to change.  My goal is to highlight a range on a spreadsheet, and then it sumproducts only rows with positive values based on the values in another equal sized range.

Comment: Basically, if I remove ```--(Rng1 > 0)``` from ```Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Rng1 > 0), Rng1, Rng2)``` I don't get an error, but I get the wrong value - which is obvious as I'm not filtering anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone gave me the answer and it is:

`Evaluate("=SUM(if(" & rng1.Address & "> 0," & rng1.Address & "*" & rng2.Address & "))")`